# How to add other content to a content-type?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, content-type, css

Salvete!  I want to create a custom content-type, but I want to add a few subtitles and maybe some custom content, such as graphics, or explanations, to the fill-in area.

How can I do that short of hacking it with javascript?

Maybe it is possible to bind an infopath form to the content-type?  The idea is that I could edit the content-type, and the changes get applied to all instances of it, whatever list it might be in.  If I could bind a particular form (newform.aspx, editform,.aspx, etc.) to the content-type, that seems like it could work, no?

Comment: Do you want to edit the content type or data based on that content type?

Comment: I don't need to edit the data.  I want to insert a sort of title to break up the questions in the forms.

Comment: You want to edit the form.

Comment: Edit what form?  I am creating a content-type, no?  How do I edit the form of a content type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much toil, I think the only way to do this is by creating an InfoPath-based content-type.  You can create the form with whatever fields you like, and add whatever styles you like.

Now, to make it work, you have to make sure your certificate is installed in Central Administration > Security > Manage Trust.  (See [this thread](http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/11/sharepoint2010-root-of-certificate.html))

Also, you have to upload a data connection file.  First, create a `Data Connections` library somewhere in your portal.  Then, in InfoPath, you have to go to (in the ribbon) Data > Data Connections, and, having selected your data connection(you know, when you told it whence to upload the submitted forms), click on "Convert to Connection File".  It will prompt you for a url with a file name.  You should specify the url to your data connection library that you just created in your sharepoint portal, and give it a file name with the extension .udcx - something like this:  http://myportal.mydomain.com/dataconnectionlibrary/myDataconnection.udcx

After that is done, you can go into your forms library and add the new content-type, complete with all your nice formatting.  If you want to display the form's fields and values like a regular list instead of like a document library, you have to create a new "standard" view.

Hope that helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You can try Forms Designer tool: http://spform.com. It allows you to edit new, edit and display forms for the specific content type. But if you need to apply it to all lists that use this content type you have to export and import setting of the form in the forms designer. Or write to support team, may be such functionality is there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion; but my boss won't let me purchase the product...